# how to create branch based project timelines

Tags: project-management-style, timeline

I am creating a forecast of a project timeline. In this I envision several swim lanes that will converge and fork as needed. sort of like product version controls.

Is there an easy way to generate this. the timelines and milestones are changing as we discover new idea/potentials.

thanks

[image: example of branch based timeline]

Comment: Are you possibly thinking of an activity-on-node diagram?

Comment: I did read up on those. I have used MS project in the past and see the "network" way of representing the timelines. but what I am doing is forecasting and I have not been able to successfully use MS project + network view. any suggestion on alternate applications to try that ?